# Pentaho CDE: Is there a way to debug the sql command being executed?

Tags: sql, pentaho

I'm wondering if there is a way to debug the sql command that SQL Query component executes at runtime?
I know placing a "console.log()" can debug components but SQL Query does not have an event to set the console up

Regards,
Erick

Comment: Are you using Pentaho Data Integration or BI Server alone?

Comment: @shzyincu it's BI server alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up debugging thru SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown Pentaho Server, goto YOURDRIVE:\pentaho\biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\classes\

Open log4j.xml and uncomment this section:

```
<!-- 
   <appender name="SQLLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
     <param name="File" value="../logs/mondrian_sql.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>

   <category name="mondrian.sql">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SQLLOG"/>
   </category>
   -->
```

GOTO YOURDRIVE:\pentaho\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\mondrian
, open mondrian.properties, make sure below code is set to "true"

mondrian.rolap.generate.formatted.sql=true

Start the Pentaho server now, it will start making mysql log file in the **"YOURDRIVE:\pentaho\biserver-ce\tomcat\logs\"** folder when you execute the sql statements...

Comment: I might missed an important thing, my Dashboard is connecting to Microsoft SQL Server.
This could be the reason that even though after enabled the log settings you mentioned, it is not capturing anything of my queries

Comment: hmmm, i will look into it later today :)